# refreshApex throwing error after modifying DOM

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a requirement to create a component that allows a user to drag records around a table. The records need to be able to move around the table and be sorted within each cell. Each cell needs to be summarized based on the cards, so the table needs to be re-rendered when a card moves.

I'm achieving this via Picklist values to determine which cell it's in (let's call this `Location__c`) and a number field (`Sort_Order__c`) to determine where it falls in the cell.

I'm using a `@wire` to get the data, then using the Drag-And-Drop API to handle the drag-and-drop. Due to the need to set sort order inside each cell, I use `insertBefore` and `appendChild` to show the user where the record will end up as the user is dragging. I think this is causing issues when I run a `refreshApex` call as I get an error:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.

The stack trace shows that the exception is ocurring in `aura_prod.js`, however given the error I'm assuming it has something to do with modifying the DOM.

Is there a way to handle a drag-and-drop experience where the user gets a preview of where the card will drop without editing DOM? Most examples I see don't show the user where the card will end up. Or is there a way to get refreshApex to handle the now modified DOM?

Below is a simplified component based on a Custom Object (`Custom_Object__c`) with `Location__c` and `Sort_Order__c` fields. The final component has far more features, but this is able to recreate the error.

Apex Class: DragAndDropController.cls

```
public with sharing class DragAndDropController {
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Custom_Object__c> getCORecords() {
        return [SELECT Id, Name, Location__c, Sort_Order__c FROM Custom_Object__c];
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void updateCORecords(List<Custom_Object__c> records){
        update records;
    }
}
```

LWC: dragAndDrop.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Drag-And-Drop Example">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>A</th>
                <th>B</th>
                <th>C</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <template for:each={tableColumns} for:item="column">
                    <td key={column.plValue}
                        data-location={column.plValue}
                        ondragover={handleTdDragOver}>

                        <template for:each={column.records} for:item="record">
                            <div style="border:1px solid black;margin:5px;"
                                key={record.Id}
                                data-id={record.Id}
                                data-sortorder={record.Sort_Order__c}
                                draggable="true"
                                ondragstart={handleDragStart}
                                ondragover={handleRecordDragOver}
                                ondragend={handleDragEnd}>

                                {record.Name}
                            </div>
                        </template>
                    </td>
                </template>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

LWC: DragAndDrop.js

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track, api } from 'lwc';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import getCORecords from '@salesforce/apex/DragAndDropController.getCORecords';
import updateCORecords from '@salesforce/apex/DragAndDropController.updateCORecords';

export default class DragAndDrop extends LightningElement {

    @wire(getCORecords) recordsWire;

    @track draggingNode;
    @track draggingId;

    get tableColumns() {
        //Not worried about error handling for this example, get data directly
        var data = this.recordsWire.data;

        if (data == null) { return; } //No data yet - jump out to avoid errors

        var buckets = {
            "A" : { plValue: "A", records: [] },
            "B" : { plValue: "B", records: [] },
            "C" : { plValue: "C", records: [] },
        }

        for (var record of data) {
            if (!record.Location__c) {
                record.Location__c = 'A'; //Set a default so it shows up
            }

            buckets[record.Location__c].records.push(record);
        }


        return [
            buckets["A"],
            buckets["B"],
            buckets["C"]
        ];
    }

    handleDragStart(event) {
        //Mark which node is being dragged for use later
        this.draggingNode = event.target;
        this.draggingId = event.target.dataset.id;
    }

    handleRecordDragOver(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        
        //If it's over the original card, don't do anything
        if (event.target.dataset.id == this.draggingId) { return; }

        //Insert the card on the parent, before the card we drag it over
        var node = event.target;
        node.parentNode.insertBefore(this.draggingNode, node);
    }

    handleTdDragOver (event) {
        //Move the node to the TD being dragged over
        event.target.appendChild(this.draggingNode);
    }

    handleDragEnd(event) {
        //figure out who needs updates and update

        var toUpdate = [];

        //Iterate over children of parent
        for (var i = 0; i < event.target.parentNode.childNodes.length; ++i) {
            var childNode = event.target.parentNode.childNodes[i];

            if (childNode.dataset.id == this.draggingId) {
                //It's the card we're dragging - change location and sort order
                toUpdate.push({
                    Id : this.draggingId,
                    Location__c : event.target.parentNode.dataset.location,
                    Sort_Order__c : i+1
                });
            } else if (childNode.dataset.sortorder != (i+1)) {
                //It's a card that got moved by the one we're dragging - update sort order
                toUpdate.push({
                    Id : childNode.dataset.id,
                    Sort_Order__c : i+1
                });
            }
        }


        updateCORecords({records : toUpdate}).then((data) => {
            refreshApex(this.recordsWire);
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        })

        this.draggingNode = null;
        this.draggingId = null;
    }


}
```

Comment: You can't use DOM manipulation without `lwc:dom="manual"`. I've linked an answer where I show how to do this in data. Just reorder the data in the array, and your template will update accordingly.

Comment: Also, to get a "preview" to show up, just insert a fake element in the data, and it'll show up in the page. If you don't get it working by tomorrow, I'll have time to write up an answer for you.